# Rails: Problems with Asset Pipelin / SASS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I have a strange problem with rails assets pipeline. In my `assets/stylesheets` folder there is an normal application.css as well as some gmaps4rails css files, and there is a `sass` subfolder with an application.sass inside.
Now something must have happend, when I change for example body cursor to pointer, having the web site open locally with rails s, then in the included compiled application.css there was no change.
Where can I look why this suddenly happens? 
How should the sass and css files be included?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that changes you make in the css / sass files are not getting reflected when you do something like "view page source".

One thing, You should disable asset pipelining in development mode. It precompiles the assets and sometimes assets don't get loaded up correctly. I have even noticed flash not getting cleared up! However you can try this:

1) Clear your browser cache.

2) In your rails app folder, go to tmp/  and delete the cache folder.

3) Now, restart your rails server.

Comment: For turning of the asset pipeline in devolopment mode, is it enough to `config.cache_classes = false`, `config.assets.compress = false` and `config.assets.debug = true` in `config/enviroments/development.rb`?

Comment: Also add config.assets.enabled = false and config.assets.precompile = false

Answer (score 0):

If application.css uses `//=require_tree` to load the stylesheet you should rename the sass file

```
sass/appplication.css.sass
```

Only Sass recognizes pure sass files. Sprockets relies on the last extension name and thus doesn'recognize a stylesheet.

However you can also rely on sass for including other files:

```
# application.sass.css
//= require_self

@import "sass/application";
```

and leave the sass file as is.

Comment: I changed the file ending.. Shouldn't this be updated instantly, e.g. while running the `rails s` server, saving something new to the `.css.sass` and hitting reload in my browser I don't see the changes

Comment: And also, it looks like it includes the css twice, in the header there is
    <link href="/assets/sass/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment(specific to production), config.assets.compile = true should help.  Which is not advised.

Preferred, run

```
 rake assets:precompile
```

after every asset pipline change.